# Tool to see CSS specificity

Tags: css, css-specificity

Does anyone know if there is some kind of tool to see/pick the best CSS selector based on CSS specificity to target a particular div?

I know what has higher specificity, but sometimes when working on other people projects where they have deeply nested selectors in there CSS,it is hard to find a way to override there stuff.

I know in Google chromes dev tool/firebug it shows a lot of information at the bottom when viewing the page source, is that something that should be used for this or is there other methods?

Comment: Opera Dragonfly shows the what is overridden and where it is, very useful

Comment: DevTools for chrome and Firebug for Firebox both show all applicable CSS rules, their origins, and which ones have been overridden.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Chrome Inspector.

[DevFest 2010 - Chrome Developer Tools - In Depth](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=flSMz0ATgoE)

[Google Chrome Developer Tools: 12 Tricks to Develop Quicker](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI)

[Google's Page on Dev Tools](http://code.google.com/intl/en/chrome/devtools/docs/videos.html)

Comment: Perhaps give a link to [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for those using Firefox too?

Comment: Well, I don't use Firefox since 3.5 So I am not sure what to look for. Feel free to add your answer though.

Comment: the last link is broken

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20120314221731/http://code.google.com/intl/EN/chrome/devtools/docs/videos.html

Comment: This answer is very unspecific.

Comment: How does one "Use Chrome Inspector" to see the CSS specificity, specifically?

Answer (score 4):

Since it's very widely used, no one's suggested it and fabianhjr suggested I do so, I'm going to recommend [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox. It's similar to Chrome's inspector, and allows you to see the CSS given to an element, as well as any overridden properties:

[image]

Comment: @Bojangels the domain qtax.se has only a image with the information it has been seized. Could you elaborate why you added the link and how this belongs to this thread?

Answer (score 0):

Would be great to see something like this in Chrome:

[image]